# dynamically created method not being called

Tags: ios, objective-c, runtime

After dynamically creating a method in the AppDelegate using `class_addMethod` from another class, it never gets called when it should.

The method I create on runtime is:

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
           openURL:(NSURL *)url {
  //Do something...
  return YES;
}
```

The code I used to create the previous method dynamically is:

```
    {
      UIApplication* app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
      class_addMethod([app class], @selector(application:openURL:), (IMP)myMethodIMP, @"B@:");
    }
```

Along with my `IMP` function:

```
    bool myMethodIMP(id self, SEL _cmd, UIApplication *application, NSURL *url)
    {
      [self application: application openURL:url];
      //Do something...
      return YES;
    }
```

I have verified that it was indeed created on my app delegate by using the `class_getInstanceMethod` method

Am I missing something?

Comment: It may be that `UIApplication` is caching that the delegate does not implement said method when the delegate is first set and, thus, never checks for an implementation again.   In general, dynamically generating methods in this pattern is rife with such fragility because it is really not at all the standard pattern of use.

Comment: @bbum That makes a lot of sense, is there a workaround to fix this while dynamically generating methods ?

Comment: You're best bet is to provide an empty implementation of said method (just `return YES;`) on the app delegate.   That way, if UIApplication is doing "responds to" caching, it'll do the right thing.  Then, swizzle as needed.

The caveat is that some of the methods-- even this method-- do have return values and, thus, a default return value may not be possible in the dummy implementation.  You may have to replace/override/swizzle before the first call always.

Comment: Can you post all scope where method_exchangeImplementation is?

Answer (score 1):

@bbum you are right,`UIApplication` cache that the delegate dones not respond to that method, so you can do like this

```
@interface UIApplication (MBShare)

@end

@implementation UIApplication (MBShare)

+ (void) load
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(setDelegate:);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(mb_setDelegate:);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(self, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod =
        class_addMethod(self,
                        originalSelector,
                        method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                        method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(self,
                                swizzledSelector,
                                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }

    });
}

- (void) mb_setDelegate: (id) delegate
{
    //hook method here
    [[MBShareApi shareInstance] hookAppDelegate: delegate];
    [self mb_setDelegate: delegate];
}

@end
```

more detail see:https://github.com/Baoge2012/MBShare/blob/master/MBShare/MBShareApi.m